# virtualenvwrapper Command '' not found, but can be installed with

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, virtualenvwrapper, ubuntu-20.04

I'm on Ubuntu WSL and installed `virtualenvwrapper` using `sudo apt install`.

As required, variable `WORKON_HOME` is correctly set to my virtual envs directory.

When I run `mkvirtualenv myawesomeproject` I get the following error :

```
created virtual environment CPython3.8.2.final.0-64 in 760ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/fred/venvs/myawesomeproject, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, CacheControl=latest, appdirs=latest, certifi=latest, chardet=latest, colorama=latest, contextlib2=latest, distlib=latest, distro=latest, html5lib=latest, idna=latest, ipaddr=latest, lockfile=latest, msgpack=latest, packaging=latest, pep517=latest, pip=latest, pkg_resources=latest, progress=latest, pyparsing=latest, pytoml=latest, requests=latest, retrying=latest, setuptools=latest, six=latest, urllib3=latest, webencodings=latest, wheel=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/fred/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1.debian)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

Command '' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install mailutils-mh  # version 1:3.7-2.1, or
sudo apt install meshio-tools  # version 4.0.4-1
sudo apt install mmh           # version 0.4-2
sudo apt install nmh           # version 1.7.1-6
sudo apt install termtris      # version 1.3-1
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add these two lines in your .bashrc file

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON='/usr/bin/python3'
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Make sure to put them in this order exactly.

The first line means that virtualenvwrapper will use python 3.
You have to replace `'/usr/bin/python3'` with your python path. You can find it by typing `which python`

Comment: Noice, works....

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar set of messages, but for a different reason. This one was my own fault. I had accidentally left a pair of empty single-quotes in my .bashrc file. Apparently this was interpreted as an attempt to specify a file to execute that has no name.

Here's the offending code:

alias='(unimportant ignore this)'; ''

Note the dangler '' at the end, after the semicolon. This was enough to generate the slew of messages above.